# hierarchical inheritance of abstract class with concrete method gives "<identifier> expected" error in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to run the following simple code,

```
public abstract class Shape{
    abstract double area();
    abstract double circumference();

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Area = "+area());
        System.out.println("Circumference = "+circumference());
    }
}

public class Circle extends Shape{
    double r;

    public double area()
    {
        return 3.14*r*r;
    }

    double circumference()
    {
        return 2*3.14*r;
    }


    Circle(double radius)
    {
        r=radius;
    }
}


public class Rectangle extends Shape{
    double x,y;

    double area()
    {
        return x*y;
    }

    double circumference()
    {
        return 2*(x+y);
    }

    Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        x = length;
        y = width;
    }
}

public class Geometry
{
    Circle r = new Circle(2.22);
    Rectangle s = new Rectangle(2.33, 3.44);
    r.show();
}
```

But I keep getting identifier expected error from Java compiler. What am I doing wrong. Everything is public and there seems to be no syntax error. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
class Geometry
{
    Circle r = new Circle(2.22);
    Rectangle s = new Rectangle(2.33, 3.44);
    r.show();
}
```

Your final statement doesn't declare a variable - it's just a statement. That needs to belong in an initializer block, constructor or method. For example:

```
public class Geometry {
    public static void showCircle() {
        Circle r = new Circle(2.22);
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle(2.33, 3.44);
        r.show();
    }
}
```

Note that this has nothing to do with inheritance - this code will give the same problem:

```
class Test {
    System.out.println("Oops");
}
```

Comment: I should crawl under a rock for a while.

Comment: Come out from under your rock and grab an IDE with syntax highlighting. Popular free IDEs include Eclipse, Netbeans, and my personal favorite, IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 4):

Your call to `r.show();` is not in a code block.  I suspect you intended to place this is a main method

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Circle r = new Circle(2.22);
    Rectangle s = new Rectangle(2.33, 3.44);
    r.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the main method:

```
public class Geometry
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Circle r = new Circle(2.22);
         Rectangle s = new Rectangle(2.33, 3.44);
         r.show();
     }
 }
```